# IIS Bad Request for the site configured with url-rewrite with ARR

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8, url-rewrite-module, arr

I have website created under IIS 8.0 in Windows 2012. An URL rewrite with ARR has created under this site which points to a linux machine (Basically to a webservice deployed in Tomcat) and through IIS there will be "GET" request where the URL is exceeding more than 5000 characters along with query string. When the URL is hit through program or in browser, I see IIS  throws "Bad Request" with Status code as 400 and no Substatus code. The same works when it is directly hit to the webservice (for tomcat Linux). I suspected the issue is because of the excess characters in the url, because when I try decreasing  the url length to 3500 characters which works without any error. Below are the configuration and settings that I have tried in IIS web.config and as well as http.sys registry, but nothing seems to be work.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151">
                    <headerLimits>
                        <add header="Content-Type" sizeLimit="100000000" />
                    </headerLimits>
                </requestLimits>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" maxUrlLength="8192" maxQueryStringLength="8192" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

http.sys Registry Settings

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\MaxFieldLength - DWORD - 65534
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\MaxRequestBytes - DWORD - 16777216
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlSegmentMaxCount - DWORD - 16383
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlSegmentMaxLength - DWORD - 32766
```

I have rebooted the Windows server after every above settings and configurations was done.

These settings and configuration are honored by IIS without url rewrite. If I try other url with length of 5000 characters for the same website its works without any error. This is appearing only for the url that has fallen under URL rewrite config. Is there any specific configurations that need to be done with respect to URL length in ARR apart from the above mentioned? Please suggest and help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my question.

The issue was on the Linux Tomcat side not on IIS, the catalina.out logs was stated as below

```
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
```

I added the configuration of maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" in server.xml of tomcat/conf. After modifying this, the issue was resolved.